# How to prevent popover scaling when keyboard appears?

Tags: ios, uikeyboard, uipopover

My iPad app has a popover with a few `UITextField`s at the top half.

When tapping a textfield, which makes the keyboard appear, iOS scales (and moves) my popover. I don't want that.

How do I prevent iOS from doing that?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48865227/1971013) suggests to override some `keyboardWillShow()` and `keyboardWillHide()` functions, but it's unclear where these are defined.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution?

Comment: Possibly you could try using popoverLayoutMargins of UIPopoverPresentationController and subtract the height of the keyboard in given margin when keyboard appears.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Leszek in the comments update the `popoverPresentationController.popoverLayoutMargins` of your `UIViewController` to accommodate the height of the keyboard:

```
func configurePopoverPresentationController() {
        let keyboardHeight = 500
        popoverPresentationController.popoverLayoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: -keyboardHeight, right: 0.0)
    }
```